# Getting error Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to have a property 'data'

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I using `chai.should();` for writing node js test case. I am calling REST API and getting the response

```
{
  "statuscode": 200,
  "message": "success",
  "data": {
    "getEducationDetails": [
      {
        "end_date": "1996-04-31",
        "degree_name": "BE",
        "degree_date": "1993-06-18",
        "location": "Hyderabad",
        "university_name": "Hyderabad",
        "institute_name": "VIT",
        "start_date": "1992-01-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to test the statuscode in the response is 200 or not and proprieties like location etc.

I have tried

```
res.body.should.have.property('data')
                    .which.is.an('object')
                    .and.has.property('getEducationDetails')
                    .which.is.an('array')
                    .and.has.property('location')
    .and.has.property('location')
```

and for stauscode

```
res.body.should.have.property('stauscode').eql(200)
```

how can I test these properties?

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-things

It will check for all object in array should contain end_date . You can do for all properties

```
res.body.data.getEducationDetails.should.all.have.property('end_date')
```